# Yii2 validate password in for RESTapi

Tags: yii2, firebase-authentication, yii2-advanced-app

If you do not use a password, the REST request passes. Otherwise, you get an error:

> Error:
>
> ```
>   "name": "Unauthorized",
>   "message": "Your request was made with invalid credentials.",
>   "code": 0,
>   "status": 401,
>   "type": "yii\\web\\UnauthorizedHttpException"
> ```

Access in User model:

```
   public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($username, $password = null)
    {
        // throw new NotSupportedException('"findIdentityByAccessToken" is not implemented.');
        //return static::findOne(['username' => $username]);

        $user = static::findOne(['username' => $username]);
        if ($user != null and $user->validatePassword($password)) {
            return $user;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And validatePassword function:

```
   public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        $hash = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($password);
        return Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
    }
```

How to authenticate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST APIs work usually by authenticating using tokens. There are different types of auth tokens. This example is using [basic auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication):

**Controller**

```php
public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }
```

You then need to add a `authorization header` to your request with the value

`Basic base64_encode(username:password)`